# How is this fluid motion called in English?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, terminology

I am considering unsteady two-dimensional potential flow of ideal fluid. In the absence of active forces fluid motion is governed by equation
$$
\rho \frac{d \vec{v}}{d t} = - \nabla p
$$
where $\rho$ is density, $\vec{v}$ is fluid velocity, $p$ is pressure and $d/dt$ denotes material derivative. The problem I am struggling with is how this fluid motion is called in English? I've found that some authors describe it as *pure inertial motion* or *fluid moves ballistically* but it seems that none of them is correct.

P.S. Don't know if it is important or not, but I study the motion of the free boundary at which pressure is constant.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)

Comment: Extending Alex's link comment, I'd call it an *inviscid fluid* (in the absence of external forces); cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inviscid_flow